# What's a good way of implementing traits/promotions/buffs?

Tags: c#

I basically need something that modifies existing code without the need to go back and change it. So for instance, if I have a game where the player or NPS can eat food to gain health back, and eating a banana gives five health, how can I make a trait that will make the banana gives ten health instead of five without going back into the original code that makes the banana award five health? Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to post the original code? What's the reason you don't want to change it?

Comment: Good code is supposed to change on it's own as you add to it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a conditional to the action, so if the player has that trait it would raise a flag, and every time the character eats a banana it would check using a if else and if the user has that trait it would heal the 10 instead of 5, hope that helps.

Comment: No, adding a check would involve modifying existing code, which is what I'm trying to avoid.